# zoom in animation imageview

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

i'm trying to scale an imageview using following code which works fine

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="6000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2"
        >
    </scale>
</set>
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        tools:src="@drawable/image"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

But it also scales the height and width of the imageview as well. Is there a way to scale an image of imageview without making the view bigger?

Comment: So you want to change the size of the image but not the size of the `ImageView`?

Comment: @HB. yes that's right

Comment: Why not just add the `ImageView` in another view then you can scale the `ImageView` and the other view will remain the same.

Comment: @HB. i'm not sure if i follow this

Comment: @HB. sorry i read it wrong. But yeah that make sense. it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work because the `ImageView` itself is scaled. So, no matter what the `scaleType` or `adjustViewBounds` is, the `ImageView` still gets scaled. The image can't be scaled separately from the view, instead you can animate the padding of the `ImageView`

My suggestion would be to add the `ImageView` in another view, for example a `RelativeLayout`, set the `RelativeLayout` to the size you want and then scale the `ImageView`.

Doing this, the `RelativeLayout` will remain the same size and can be used to do what your where intended to do, while the `ImageView` is scaled.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your image auto resize to fit the imageView like this

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@id/img_id"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

`adjustViewBounds` is the key to re-scale your image to fill the imageView

Comment: i want image to stay scaled after the animation. Is there a way to do that. I tried `adjustViewBounds` it doesn't work.

Comment: What's the problem exactly ? does it scale but go back to original scale when animation finishes ? or does the image doesn't get scaled at all ?

Comment: image gets scaled but it also changes the height and width of the view as well. i wan t height and width to stay the same

Comment: Try change `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` to `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`  and please post your xml code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191761/discussion-between-abhi-and-amine).